# Which python stack to choose for simple editable table

Tags: python, stack

I plan to make a simple webpage with simple (big) table. The table must be editable in place and changes instantly propagated among all users looking at it (no username/login required). I already have a script in python that scans list of devices which will be used to show them in the table.

What is the best choice of stack for this mini project?

Thanks for any advices!

Comment: Maybe a few lines of example data and some code snippets would make it easier for folks trying to understand the problem. But I have a few ideas here, not limited to the python language only. For "changes instantly propagated", I think websocket is way to go, you can build heavily interactive applications upon it. For possible huge table updates, differential updating is a common and easy practice.

Comment: There is not much to show. The important point is that that already working script can just dump those data into DB and it's written in python.
When it comes to table, it would be preferred to python because that's the one I know but I know it may not be that complicated so other options are fine too.

Comment: I searched for so options and I guess Django with Channels (websocket) with datatables and X-Editable should do. What do you think?

Comment: That should serve you well I think. Django is flexible and powerful enough for mini projects.